# Action method is passed instance of type instead of null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I've seen a lot of posts with `Url.Action` passing null instead of the value, but none with my issue. I have one link that i want to be able to call a method with a null value.

The method is

```
public ActionResult ImpersonatePost(Role Role)
{
    Authentication.Impersonating = Role;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

in the controller `Impersonate`.

I have tried the following but they all end up with `Role` being equal to `new Role()` instead of `null`. `Role` is a `class`.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ImpersonatePost", "Impersonate", null)">None</a>

<a href="@Url.Action("ImpersonatePost", "Impersonate", default(Namespace.Role))">None</a>
```

Per Request Role is defined as (in format not actual properties

```
public class Role
{
    String Property {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What is Role defined as?

Comment: `Url.Action` returns a string, not a new `Role`. Do you mean that the role *parameter in the action method* is a `Role` and not `null` when the action method executes? That's because of model binding.

Comment: @bzlm yes i mean when the ImpersonatePost method is called Role is equal to new Role() not null.

Comment: @Manatherin, again, **this has nothing to do with Url.Action. Url.Action only builds the URL for the action method, it doesn't return or create or execute anything** beyond the URL string. The reason why Role is an instance of a Role (what you refer to as "equal to new Role()" for some reason) is because that's how the default model binder works for a HTTP POST to the Impersonate action method - it's attempting to fill the properties of a Role it creates using the values from the HTTP POST. For non-complex model binding, there's no real way to do it differently.

Comment: @bzlm, move your (correct) answer down below please.

Comment: @bzlm, ok i accept i have miscommunicated the Url.Action in this, although i am refering more to the object route parameter. I would like you to post yours as a answer as what im attempting seems to be wrong. Just out of curiosity, why does this work `<a href="@Url.Action("ImpersonatePost", "Impersonate", new { Role = new ProjectSelectionAndAllocation.Models.Role() })">` Role is equal to null in ImpersonatePost when i use that

Comment: @bzlm also the method impersonate post is not actually a HTTP POST

Comment: @KirkWoll, it's better that someone who knows the nomenclature and is willing to put the effort writes a more complete answer. Which has now happened. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the ASP.Net MVC3 default optional parameter binder. There is no proper way to make an optional url parameter bind to null.

If you really want to allow for a null parameter, I'd suggest adding it to your routing initialization code in the global.asax file.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                "Custom", 
                "{controller}/{action}/{nullableParamName}", 

            );
```

If you have a method expecting nullableParamName in its route and it doesn't see that, it will take the nullableParamName in as null.